# Outlook default categories are adding to category list when trying to add custom categories using redemption

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I have a outlook plugin that add custom categories to outlook when add-in startup completes.

```
 public void CreateCategories()
        {
            RDOCategories categories = null;
            RDOCategory category = null;            

            try
            {
                var customCategoryList = FileManager.GetCustomCategoryList();
                categories = rSession.Categories;

                // add category 
                foreach (var customCategory in customCategoryList)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        category = categories.Add(customCategory.Name
                                               , PaintHelper.GetHexCodeByColorName(customCategory.Color));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                       
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (category != null)
                        {
                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(category);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
            finally
            {
                if (categories != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(categories);
                }
            }
        }
```

when I delete all categories from outlook and try to run the plugin still it shows count of **rSession.categories** as 6 and it adds all default 6 categories along with the custom categories.

Can we omit adding default categories when all outlook categories are deleted.

Comment: Why do you need to use Redemption for dealing with categories in Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.categories) property of the [NameSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace) object to obtain a `Categories` object reference, representing the `Master Category List` for that namespace.

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
// ...
private void EnumerateCategories()
{
    Outlook.Categories categories =
        Application.Session.Categories;
    foreach (Outlook.Category category in categories)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(category.Name);
        Debug.WriteLine(category.CategoryID);
    }
}

private void AddACategory()
{
    Outlook.Categories categories =
        Application.Session.Categories;
    if (!CategoryExists("MyCategory"))
    {
        Outlook.Category category = categories.Add("MyCategory",
            Outlook.OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorDarkBlue,
            Outlook.OlCategoryShortcutKey.olCategoryShortcutKeyCtrlF11);
    }
}

private bool CategoryExists(string categoryName)
{
    try
    {
        Outlook.Category category = 
            Application.Session.Categories[categoryName];
        if(category != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch { return false; }
}
```

The `AddACategory` procedure gets the current user’s main list of categories and uses the `CategoryExists` method to check whether a category named `MyCategory` exists in the collection. If no category with the name `MyCategory` exists, `AddACategory` adds a category named “MyCategory” to the main category list and assigns it a dark blue color by using the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.categories.add) method of the `Categories` collection.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no categories, Redemption assumes it is a brand new store never touched by Outlook, and adds the default categories.

Try to delete the default categories *after* adding your custom categories.